# Non-breaking sections/strings of text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I know that Word supports non-breaking characters like spaces, but you have to manually insert them.  This is very tedious when you want to make the following text non-breaking:

```
<!--<add key="env" value="prod" />-->
```

Would be nice if there were a way to highlight a string of text, right-click, and select "make non-breaking" to turn all breaking characters into non-breaking characters.

Comment: spaces and hyphens are breaking characters, any others? Ctrl-Shift-space and Ctrl-Shift-hyphen are far easier than highlighting text and bringing up a context menu, isn't it?

Comment: @fred_dot_u maybe OP doesn't type that text,  but receives it?

Comment: That makes good sense in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the text, and then do a couple of quick find and replace all (within the selection):
1.  for find: type a single space then for replace: type `^s`
2.  for find: type the single hyphen. ie `-` then for replace: type `^~`

If it's something you do often, you could write a short macro to do those 2 find and replace all actions to selected text.